# C++11 std::regex lookbehind alternative

Tags: c++, regex, lookbehind

I try to make class in C++11 to calculate math formula given as std::string.

```
std::string formula = "sqrt(3)+15*3*(2+3*4)+pow(2,3)+(2*(1+8))-(3*(1+pow(2,4)))";
```

I have decided to use std::regex to search for patterns, take them, calculate them and replace them with calculation result. To calculate this formula I made 3 patterns.

```
std::regex exprOne{ "[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\([^(),]+\\)" };
std::regex exprTwo{ "[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\([^()]+\\)" };
std::regex exprZero{ "(?![a-z0-9])\\([^(),]+\\)" };
```

exprOne matches `sqrt(3)`
exprTwo matches `pow(2,3)` and `pow(2,4)`
but problem are with exprZero it needs to match `(2+3*4)` and `(1+8)`, but it matches `sqrt(3)` too. On internet I found lookbehind `(?<![a-z0-9])`, but std::regex don't have lookbehind as I found on internet. Some suggest to use Boost.Regex, but I want to not use external libraries. If std::regex don't have lookbehind you should be able to do similar thing not using it?

exprZero should not match `sqrt([^(),]+)`, `log([^(),]+)`, `log10([^(),]+)` and so on, but should match `([^(),]+)`.

Is here a pattern in std::regex to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a non-word boundary here:

```
std::regex exprZero{R"(\B\([^(),]+\))"};
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UdCsm7/1)

The `\B\([^(),]+\)` pattern will match a `(` that is either at the start of a string or right after a non-word char (a char other than a letter, digit or `_`), `[^(),]+` will consume 1 or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `,` and then `\)` will match a `)` char.